# UnicodeDecodeError when download corpora NLTK with python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, anaconda

i think that i installed nltk packages successively
when i typed below sentences i got error.
is that error from installing? or coding?

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import nltk
nltk.download()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Lab/crawling/crawling_practice.py", line 2, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 155, in <module>
    from nltk.data import load
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\nltk\data.py", line 77, in <module>
    if 'APPENGINE_RUNTIME' not in os.environ and os.path.expanduser('~/') != '~/':
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 311, in expanduser
    return userhome + path[i:]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What is your username on your machine? Does it contain some sort of latin character with accent/grave marks?

Comment: actually it was failed in python2.7. i changed it to version3.5. it did work successfully

Answer (score 0):

What Python editor are you using? The `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` head comment is only supported in some editors. For all editors should work `# coding=<encoding name>`. Please read the docs fire more information. 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263. 
What also could be, is that the filepath where nltk tries to download itself or your username contains any Unicode characters (see last traceback line)

Comment: thank you for tagging the comments. what you told me could be problem. but to me, the main problem might be version.

Comment: Yes, it's important to have the right version of nltk (which matches the Python version) Do you have a solution now? Maybe read this:. http://lizusefulstuff.blogspot.de/2012/03/how-to-install-nltk-package-for-python.html?m=1